# Extjs: rendering data when store loads

Tags: extjs4.1

I designed my extjs4 application as mvc.
Sometimes, under certain unclear circumstances, when I load remote data into a store from the controller, the view does not reflect the changes; this happends for comboboxes and for grids.
It's like I am missing something about the extjs design, and with this question I hope to get things clearer.

Consider this example which is not working for me:

*The controller:*

```
...
init: function() {
    this.control({
        // * This is the alias of a grid panel. 
        // * When I dbl-click a record, I want to display it in a modal window
        'w_fares_index': {
            itemdblclick: function(grid, record) {
                var view = Ext.widget('w_fares_edit');
                view.down('form').loadRecord(record);

                var store = this.getStore('StoreBillsModels');
                store.load({
                    params: {
                        'where': {
                            "id_fare": record.get('id')
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        },
...
```

*The view*:

```
...
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias : 'widget.w_fares_edit',
...
items[{
    xtype: 'form',
    ...
}, {
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    store: 'StoreBillsModels',
    columns: [{
        header: 'Id',
        dataIndex: 'id',
        flex: 1
    }, ...]
}]
```

With this code, the new modal window opens, and the clicked record is loaded into the form. But, even if the store StoreBillsModels is populated (i can see it analysing network requests), the grid panel inside the new window does not show any record.

Plus, I noticed something strange:

- If StoreBillsModels's size is 1, then the grid shows an empty white line
- If the store size is 0, the grid shows only the headers and has no height

I encountered more or less the same problem with comboboxes.. It's like if I populate the store within the same function that materialize the view, then the store consumer does not reflect store changes.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

My store had this property:

```
buffered: true
```

I don't know why, but if the store is buffered, i experience the problem asked above.
I solve the problem by setting:

```
buffered: false
```